# AS2 SWF works standalone, but when included into AS3 SWF (even when ONLY it is loaded) it acts strangely, any ideas?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, gallery

I am aware that there are a few posts on loading AS2 SWF's into AS3 SWF's but none provide a solution! I have a standalone image gallery - using an XML file - that I have loaded into an AS3 SWF.

The gallery functions fine on it's own, but when loaded into an AS3 SWF, it does not change the main image! I created a new AS3 SWF, and had ONLY the code to load this AS2 gallery into the AS3 movie, nothing else, and still it refused to change the large image when the thumbnails were clicked. The gallery pretty much run's perfectly fine, it is ONLY the large image that is not working. Can anyone help on this one? Here is my AS2 main gallery code, can someone spot something that could be causing the error?

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

var my_xml = new XML();
my_xml.ignoreWhite = true;

my_xml.onLoad = function(success){
    if(success){
        doGallery();
        }
    else{
        null;
        }
    }

my_xml.load("xml/gallery.xml");

function doGallery(){

    var imgTitles:Array = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.imgtitles.split("|");
    var numImgs:Number = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.num;
    var thumbprefix = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.thumbprefix;
    var largeprefix = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.largeprefix;
    var ext = "."+my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.ext;
    var imgSets:Number = Math.ceil(numImgs/10);//max possible number of image sets
    var desc:Array = my_xml.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.descriptions.split("|")

    _parent.mySets = imgSets;
        if(imgSets == 1){
        _parent.btnNxt._visible = false;
        }

    _parent.imgNum = "1/"+numImgs;
    _parent.imgHolder.imgAttach.loadMovie("gallery/"+largeprefix+"01"+ext);

    for(var i:Number=0;i<numImgs;i++){

        attachMovie("thumbframe", "thumb"+i, this.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:(i * 20), _y:51});
        var clip = eval("thumb"+i);

        if(i == 0){clip._x = 39;}
        else{clip._x = 90 * (i)+39;}

        clip._y = 51;


        _parent.txtsimon = imgTitles[0];
        _parent.imgDescr = desc[0];

        eval("thumb"+i).id = i+1;

        if(imgTitles[i] == "" or imgTitles[i] == undefined){
            clip.title = "Untitled Image";
        }
        else{
            clip.title = imgTitles[i];
        }


        eval("thumb"+i).thumbhold.loadMovie("gallery/"+thumbprefix+"0"+eval("thumb"+i).id+ext);

        eval("thumb"+(i)).onRelease = function(){   

            _parent.imgNum = this.id+"/"+numImgs;
            var thumbid:Number = this.id;
            var imgOut:Tween = new Tween(_parent.imgHolder, "_alpha", Regular.easeOut, _parent.imgHolder._alpha, 0, 0.4, true)

            imgOut.onMotionFinished = function(){
                _root.container.imgHolder.imgAttach.unloadMovie();
                _root.container.imgHolder.imgAttach.loadMovie("gallery/"+largeprefix+"0"+thumbid+ext);
                trace("gallery/"+largeprefix+"0"+thumbid+ext);
                new Tween(_root.container.imgHolder, "_alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0, 100, 0.5, true);
            }
            mytitle = this.title;
            _parent.txtsimon = mytitle;
            _parent.imgDescr = this.descr;

            _parent.btnDownloadImg.onRelease = function(){
                getURL("gallery/"+largeprefix+"0"+thumbid+ext);
                }

            new Tween(activeThumb, "_x", Strong.easeOut, activeThumb._x, this._x, 1.5, true);
            }

        clip.onRollOver = function(){
            new Tween(this, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, this._alpha, 75, 1, true);
            }

        clip.onRollOut = function(){
            new Tween(this, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, this._alpha, 100, 1, true);
            }
        }

        _parent.btnSlideShow.onRelease = function(){
        new Tween(this._parent.slideOverlay, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 100, 3, true);        
        }
}

        _parent.btn_requestHighRes.onRelease = function(){
            var rtitle:String = _parent.txtsimon.toString();
            getURL("mailto:HIDDEN_EMAIL?subject=Toolkit High Res Request - "+rtitle);
            }
```

I have run a trace on the source of the large image, and it is calling the correct image. I unload the current image and load in the new image, but STILL the old one loads in, like it's cached or something?? The issue seems to be near this code:

```
_root.container.imgHolder.imgAttach.unloadMovie();
_root.container.imgHolder.imgAttach.loadMovie("gallery/"+largeprefix+"0"+thumbid+ext);
trace("gallery/"+largeprefix+"0"+thumbid+ext);
```

The above trace shows me that the correct image is being called, but it simply will not load in!

I appreciate all comments greatly as I have sat on this one for ages!

Simon

Comment: Best thing you can do is translate it to AS3. I've seen various bugs when AS2 loaded into AS3, like: mouse handler on sprite not called, mouse wheel not working, some parts shifted/missing. Stage width is seen as 0 when AS2 loaded into AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a AVM1 inside a AVM2 (SWF with Actionscript 1.0/2.0 into SWF Actionscript 3.0) **[has some restrictions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html)**, but I don't think that you are dealing with one of them...

Anyway, checkout **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874990/loading-external-pngs-into-an-as2-swf-that-is-loaded-into-an-as3-swf-wrapper)**.

Hopes that will help.

Comment: thank you for your reply, however that thread seemed a little irrelevant in my circumstance as the gallery is functioning 99.9%, I was just having issues with loading / unloading the PNG images into my frame holder. After MUCH trial and error it seems I have cracked it, using a nasty nasty bunch of code. It's like 10tons of code being held by a single thread, that's how cautious I am of it! but it works, and it works well. Will post below...